# Cannot update Android version on my Oukitel RT3 after unrooting it

Tags: root-access, ota-update

It's been a while since I've rooted my Oukitel RT3. After seeing that an update was available, I unrooted it so I could install it without any problem. The only problem is that it says this:

> #### Couldn't update
>
> Installation problem
>
> **V07_20230215 to V10_20230711**
>
> **Update size: 43.91 MB**

<sup>[Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Que.png)</sup>

I think it's because I swapped the Magisk patched boot image with the system one, but the version of the ROM on the Oukitel website was outdated. So, my device shows that the ROM version is V07_20230215 (the actual ROM with the boot image needed, but can't find it on the internet) but on the website, the latest available is V05_20221117 (which is the one I took the boot image from), and the one I have to update to is V10_20230711.

Maybe I followed the wrong steps to unroot it, can anyone help?

Comment: If you had unrooted it via Magisk by uninstalling it, Magisk would have restored the corresponding stock image.. Just saying because you didn't say how you unrooted

Comment: To unroot it i simply swapped the magisk patched one with the stock one, the problem is that the one magisk used is an old one because to install it i had to find the boot image of the current ROM but I couldn't find the newer one because the website of the phone manufacturer had the older ones, not the newer so the patched boot image has the older one, so I don't have the boot image of the actual ROM. I can't find the V07_20230215 boot image

Comment: My RT3 is box stock and it will not update android 12 as well. The RT3 seems a bit clunky to use on the whole. They (Oukitel) need to sort this.